# Issues using angular-piwik

Tags: angularjs, matomo

I am using https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik for tracking a single page angular web application. I have included page tracking snippet in index.html using angular-piwik directive as under:

<ngp-piwik ngp-set-js-url="//.../piwik.js" ngp-set-tracker-url="//.../piwik.php" ngp-set-site-id="1"></ngp-piwik>

And inject Piwik service in my app module.

I have below issues:

1. Error "The method setTrackerUrl is registered more than once in "_paq" variable. Only the last call has an effect." shows up in console. Same error is thrown for setSiteId method as well. In spite of these 2 errors, I am able to see my page getting tracked on Piwik dashboard. I want to get rid of these 2 errors.
2. Unable to track individual states/urls implemented using angular ui-view. I want to track all the urls that are defined in my application using $stateProvider and their usage should show under Piwik pages log under actions tab.
3. There is not enough documentation/example for using angular-piwik.

Comment: RE: #1 - This is a known issue and will be fixed with an updated PR here https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik/pull/3 (or perhaps in another PR with the same purpose).

Comment: RE: #2 - Can you provide some code the demonstrates how you are currently trying to do this, and what you are trying to track?

Comment: RE: #3 - what in particular would you find useful in the docs?  I am happy to add more documentation, but only want to add content that real users find valuable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in 1.3.1.  Please update to this version.

https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik/tree/1.3.1